# Solve for the Power required by the driven wheels. All the given information is In the image posted below

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image: .]

Solve for the Power required by the driven wheels. All the given information is In the image posted below. Solve for the Power required by the driven wheels. All the given information is In the image posted below

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I won't do your homework for you but I will describe what you need to do. The power requirement is work done (resisting force x distance) per unit time or resisting force x velocity. Ignoring friction, the resisting force is the component of the weight acting down the slope which is the weight times the sine of the angle to the horizontal. Then just multiply by the velocity.